# How to associate Okta users to specific redshift database group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, database-administration, okta, okta-api

I am trying to get users onboarded on Redshift using Okta and wanted to know how we can associate an okta user to a specific database group(s) in redshift. I want to do this so that we can control access to database schemas/objects based on permissions granted to Redshift Database group.

Comment: Have these links been helpful? https://saml-doc.okta.com/SAML_Docs/How-to-Configure-SAML-2.0-for-Amazon-Web-Services-Redshift.html or https://support.okta.com/help/answers?id=9060Z00000078L6QAI&feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=xProvisioning&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned in first link. I suspect that "Allowed DB Groups (Redshift)" defines what database groups a user gets access to. But I am not able to test that as I am getting below error after following all steps mentioned in first link. Do you know what could be missing?

[JDBC Driver]SAML error: Unauthorized

Comment: I haven't tried this integration before so I'm not sure, but you might want to try asking your question on the developer forum, https://devforum.okta.com/

Comment: Thanks. I have reached Okta support to see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Okta support to get it clarified and while configuring Okta application (Redshift) we do have an option where we can specify the database groups to which users will be added to while creating their accounts. However, We will need to create multiple applications for multiple level of access to different users.